# Accessing a variable between two files

Tags: variables, unity-game-engine, click, unityscript

I am trying to access the variable can (which i am trying to be a boolean telling me if someone clicked my text box) in my second file named upgradeBBPS.js so i can apply this javascript(upgradeBBPS.js) to my textbox, and check every frame to see if they clicked the textbox. What i want the textbox is to return a boolean (true/false) to the first javascript file (Main.js) and then make the clickVal become the value of clickVal*1.2.

File 1: Main.js

```
pragma strict
var clicks : GameObject;

var score : UnityEngine.UI.Text;

var clicked : boolean = false;

var baconBits : int = 0;

var clickVal : int = 1;

var baconBitMultCost : int = 10;

//var can : GameObject;

public var can;

function Start () {

}

function Update () {

 score.text = "Bacon Bits: " + baconBits;

}

function OnMouseDown () {

 baconBits += clickVal;

}

function baconBitMultiplier(can) {

 if(boolean)
 {

     if(baconBits>=baconBitMultCost)
     {

         clickVal+=1;

         baconBitMultCost*= 1.2;

     }
 }
}
```

File 2: upgradeBBPS.js

```
pragma strict
//var can : boolean;

function Start () {

}

function Update () {

 //Main.getComponent(can) =true;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing a variable in a script that is attached to same GameObject as the first script can be done this way:

```
var bbps: upgradeBBPS;
bbps = gameObject.GetComponent(upgradeBBPS);
bbps.can = true;
```

The code is first getting the other component and then setting the variable. (`gameObject` refers to the GameObject in which component containing this code is attached to.)

If the other script is attached to another GameObject, that GameObject needs to be found first:

```
var go : GameObject;
go = GameObject.Find("YourGameObjectName");
var bbps: upgradeBBPS;
bbps = go.GetComponent(upgradeBBPS);
bbps.can = true;
```

Just change the `"YourGameObjectName"`to actual name of your GameObject.

Comment: So which file do i put either one of those in? thanks and if you could elaborate more on gameobjects that would be awesome!

Comment: If you want to find `upgradeBBPS.js` from `Main.js`, you put code trying to find `upgradeBBPS`into the `Main.js`. They are attached to the same GameObject (and you can use the first script), if you can see both them at the same time in the `Inspector` view.